# How to prevent going to order view in order grid view (list view)?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

In the magento **Sales > Orders** view where it lists all orders.
I am trying to prevent the redirection when clicking on the order row  (*admin/sales_order/view/order_id/{orderID}*)
I would like to keep the action when the "view" link is clicked but prevent it if clicked anywhere else.

I process orders from the list view and copying information is a pain requiring me to hit escape every time I try (and sometimes redirects anyway)

Answer (score 1):

What's causing this is you have `<td>`s with a link in their title.
You need to modify `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php`  and comment the inside of the following function:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    //if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        //return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    //}
    return false;
}
```

This should remove the link from the rows and still let you click the "view" link.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Idk whats causing it but it's been doing that as long as I can remember (2-3 years)... I will check to see if this works and let you know...

Comment: It has that without the "//"     I tried adding the "//" but it didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: What I meant was: "have your function be like the one below". Or comment the `return false;` too, see if that helps.

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question but do I need to reindex after making the change?

Comment: Nah this has nothing to do with indexes you're fine.